# website hosted on firebase cannot connect to an aws ec2 node server

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-ec2

I'm hosting a website using firebase. I am also hosting a node server on aws  ec2.

For some reason my website is getting an error:

```
net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I don't know why this is happening. I'm not sure how to fix this so my website can run correctly.

///

Edit website is connection to a node server hosted on aws ec2. The node server is ran by express using socket.io

Comment: can you show us the ajax call that produces this error?

Comment: it's not an ajax call. IT's a socket.io connection

Comment: Have you configured ssl certificate in your server?

Comment: This makes sense. I'm working on this right now. 

Bad practice, but I have another website that didn't require this. But that was probably because the hosted website wasn't https. 


The website I'm asking about is HTTPS. So it's trying to communicate to a server that isn't HTTPS. This makes sense.